# How to dynamically modify callers name

Tags: android, contacts

Is there a way how to dynamically modify the name that appears on the screen when somebody is calling?

For instance, I have a number "123456789" in my contact list under the name "Bill Gates". Now when the number "123456789" calls me, I want the corresponding name that appears on the screen to be changed to for instance "Test".

I have a broadcast receiver that is listening to incoming calls. Once I get the call with particular number (123456789), I change the contact name to the corresponding value (Test).

The contact name gets changed to "Test", however the name visible on the screen during the phone call does not change.

Isn't there something like an observer pattern where all the receivers get notified once the contact has been updated?

I tried `contentResolver.notifyChange(URI_CONTACTS, null, true)`, however does not work

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way how to dynamically modify the name that appears on the screen when somebody is calling?

No, at least no universal method which fits your scenario. The phone app would have to check for changes of the caller name by itself. As your test shows this does not apply to the phone app you are using.

> Isn't there something like an observer pattern where all the receivers get notified once the contact has been updated?

Still, the phone app would have to register itself as an observer.